# UIImagePickerController record video with landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller

How can we force UIImagePickerController controller to record video only in landscape mode?

I know that this class should be used for portrait recording, but I need to have it in landscape.

Have found several similar questions but there is not any solution which works for me (iOS 6.1).

For example observation of device orientation  doesn't work for me (this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2147584/775779)

If I implement UIImagePickerController category like the following:

```
#import "UIImagePickerController+NonRotating.h"

@implementation UIImagePickerController (NonRotating)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

@end
```

it almost works, but I see some strange behavior of some controls and wrong video orientation during recording (the result video is ok).

1) Start. Cancel and recording button in the right positions, but other controls in wrong. And video is rotated.
[image]

2) Recording. Timer and video are wrong.
[image]

3) Recording finished. all good! and the result video is right.

[image]

do you have any ideas?

**UPDATE** 
I need to lock the screen in Landscape orientation during the recording process.

Comment: please don't close this question. the question which you gave a link doesn't have the right answer and all solutions from that comments don't work.

Comment: @iPatel have you read my question? I already told about this link.

Comment: have you tried setting the video orientation?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811641/ios-camera-orientation#14812010

Comment: @Gotschi no, have not tried. I don't use AVCaptureConnection, I use UIImagePickerController

Comment: you have to rotate the device some how .... :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a custom `UIImagePickerController`. 
For that, you'll need to set imagepicker's property `showsCameraControls` to FALSE.

```
self.mImagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.mImagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Once you do this, no default controls will be visible to you. You'll need to setup custom buttons for start/stop recording and flipping camera etc.

Now, you can use the start/stop methods to record a video:

When one clicks on start recording,

```
[self.mImagePickerController startVideoCapture];
```

To stop,

```
[self.mImagePickerController stopVideoCapture];
```

To keep track of the switching between the camera, you can use a flag

```
if (self.mImagePickerController.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear)
    {
        self.mImagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        isFrontCamera = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.mImagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        isFrontCamera = NO;
    }
```

You can set the controls as you wish on the orientation change. 
AppDelegate.m

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

This is the delegate that gets called on orientation change. You can use the particular class's object to call its shouldAutorotate method and setup your camera control positions according to the orientation.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    [self.objController shouldAutorotate];
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Now inside cameraviewcontroller.m

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        // your controls setup
    }
    else
    {
        // view accordingly for landscape 
    }
}
```

I have tried to cover all the points. Let me know if you have any confusion. Hope it helps :)

1) You need to check the condition on click event of the flip camera button.

2) AppDelegate.h: Declare an object of your class where you record your video and create a property. Here I'm using `CameraViewController` as an example.

```
CameraViewController *objController;
```

Now in AppDelegate.m:

```
self.objController = [[CameraViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CameraViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Now use this instance to call the `shouldAutorotate` method as I have shown above. And return landscape orientation:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if(isOptionScreenActive == YES)
    {
        [self.shareController shouldAutorotate];
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else
    {
        [self.anotherController shouldAutorotate];
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Here `isOptionScreenActive` is a `flag` that is set in the `viewWillAppear` of the recording class. Set it `false` in `viewDidUnload`. Or may be `viewWillAppear` of another class.

3) I have used cameraviewcontroller.m just as an example. It reflects your recording class. Also in your video recording class's `shouldAutorotate` method, if the detected orientation is portrait, just return NO. This way the UI wont change and you can keep the UI in landscape only.

Comment: thanks for the comment. several questions before I try to implement this: 1) "To keep track of the switching between the camera, you can use a flag" - can't figure out where this code should be. 2) "This is the delegate that gets called on orientation change. You can use the particular class's object to call its shouldAutorotate method and setup your camera control positions according to the orientation. " - "self.objController" - what is this? I have just one screen where I record video. It should be landscape. Others are in portrait orientation. 3) cameraviewcontroller.m - what is this?

Comment: and I see that with your solution it will support both orientations. just with custom controls. I need to make it work *only* in landscape orientation. to lock it.

Comment: I have updated the answer to accomodate your queries. See if it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'll award you the bounty, because your answer is the best one. but I can't check it now, so I can't accept it. I'll check it later and maybe will ask some additional questions.

Comment: @Maverick hey, I was wondering does setting `picker.showsCameraControls = NO;` remove the auto focus function?

Answer (score 0):

try this on may it w'll help you

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||       interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

it w'lll work...:)

Comment: thanks for the comment. have tried it out, but have got an exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'

Comment: It will work if we add - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
} instead of -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}