# how to get the orientation of device when use camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, avfoundation

i want to know the orientation of the phone when i take photograph,i use :

```
  NSLog(@"%ld", self.interfaceOrientation);
  NSLog(@"%ld", [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation);
  NSLog(@"%ld", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);
```

but no matter what orientation i really is ,the codes all print 1 1 1 ,which stands UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;
in my app targets ,the device orientation i choose portrait only,

is this the reason make the code shows a incorrect result?

how can i get the true orientation???????

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: camera orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811641/ios-camera-orientation)

Answer (score 0):

By default camera orientation is `UIInterfaceOrientationLeft`, if you want to change orientation using camera, you have to do it manually.

```
AVCaptureConnection *conn=self.previewLayer.connection;

if ([conn isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            [conn setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [conn setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight]; 
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            [conn setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft]; 
            break;
        default:
            [conn setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait]; 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the situation i want is : no matter what kind of  orientation the phone is when i taking photographs ,the photo always looks the same orientation as what we can see in eyes;; so ,when i take photographs ,i need to know if i changed the orientation.....

Comment: by posting the code, do you mean that "AVCaptureConnection *conn=self.previewLayer.connection;" can determin the photograph's orientation,so i can set the conn to the "toInterfaceOrientation" orientataion?

Comment: Actually it determines how you can access orientation mode and use it as you needed. Anyways you have to do it manually, iOS not going to return you orientation on camera run.

Comment: if i want to correct the photograph's orientation,first i need to know how it goes wrong,it means i need to know the phone's orientation when i taking photographs... ...;if ios does not support the orientation on camera run,it means i need to figure out how the phone rotating - -!...  is there any methods i can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the orientation of device, as you fixed the supported interface orientations to Portrait, Also enable the landscape orientation and try the below code,

```
UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)){
    NSLog(@"Landscape Orientation");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Portrait Orientation");
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it does not work  ,still always shows UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;do you mean that because i choose Portrait only,so the orientation does not show correct....   ;if this ,is there any ways that i can figure out when i am rotating the phone ?

Comment: yes, this is because you choose UIDeviceOrientationPortrait only in app target.  This method  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` gives the orientation of app, but not the device. In order to get the correct orientation, You need to choose the landscape orientation too(in application targets)

Comment: interfaceOrientation != deviceOrientation...  Different beasts.  You can specify interfaceOrientations in a plist but can you limit how the device is actually handled in 3d space?

Comment: "choose the landscape orientation " still not helps - -!;just as @ iOSNoob sayed "iOS not going to return you orientation on camera run"~~~~~~~~

Comment: Exactly, interfaceOrientation != deviceOrientation, and if we allow the device to rotate the applications orientation to match the device orientation(By selecting the supported interface orientations to Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape Left and Landscape Right in Targets ) , then there is possibility to get the correct orientation.

Comment: do you mean  that the interfaceOrientation is the app's orientation,and the deviceOrientation is the phone's orientation;if we set the device can change the app's orientation,the interfaceOrientation shows the correct orientation,otherwise,it shows default;